# insert with select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables master, element, check.

**master**

```
master_id,           
master_name,
```

**element**

```
element_id,                                
element_name,
```

**check**

```
(master_id)
(element_id)
check_id
check_name
description
```

I want to insert values into `check` table such as `check_id,check_name,description` with `master_id` from `master` table and `element_id` from `element` table.

I tried the following query.

```
insert 
into CHECK values((select e.ELEMENT_ID,m.MASTER_ID from MASTER as m,ELEMENT as e where m.MASTER_ID=3 and ELEMENT_ID=3),'M001','chkitem1','Check description',)
```

It throws me the following error.

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

can anyone give an idea for this..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **EITHER** have something like

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Yourtable(list of columns)
VALUES (list of scalar, atomic values)
```

but then you need to provide atomic, scalar values - literals or variables.

**OR** you use this syntax

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(list of columns)
  SELECT (list of columns) 
  FROM dbo.YOurSourceTable ......
```

but in this case, you **don't** specify the `VALUES` keyword.

So in your case, try:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CHECK(master_id, element_id, check_id, check_name, description)
  SELECT 
      e.ELEMENT_ID, m.MASTER_ID, 'M001', 'chkitem1', 'Check description'
  FROM 
      dbo.MASTER AS m
  INNER JOIN
      dbo.ELEMENT AS e ON m.MASTER_ID = e.ELEMENT_ID
  WHERE
       m.Master_ID = 3
```

Also: don't use the old-style JOIN of just comma-separating a list of tables in the `FROM` clause - that's been deprecated with the **SQL-92** standard, more than 20 years ago! Use the proper ANSI JOIN with `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

**Update:** ok, so you seem to be inserting something into the `Master` table first (wasn't clear from your question) and then you want to use that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in the subsequent insert - try this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Master(list-of-columns) VALUES(.........)

DECLARE @MasterID INT
SELECT @MasterID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.CHECK(master_id, element_id, check_id, check_name, description)
  SELECT 
      e.ELEMENT_ID, @MasterID, 'M001', 'chkitem1', 'Check description'
  FROM 
      dbo.MASTER AS m
  INNER JOIN
      dbo.ELEMENT AS e ON m.MASTER_ID = e.ELEMENT_ID
  WHERE
       m.Master_ID = @MasterID
```

Comment: This works fine..but i want get the "master_id" as scope_identity() value from "master" table, and insert that with "check" table column values...can u help me..?

Comment: yes, exactly First am inserting some data into the Master table. 2.getting the master_id by using Scope_identity().                  3.insert that scope_identity with check table columns such as (master_id, element_id,check_id,check_name,description). Final output of the "check" table should be Master_id(from master table),element_id(from element table),check_id,check_name,description.  Is that understandable..?